# How to print "NO MATCH FOUND" only once after scanning a external file for a match?

Tags: java

I have a quick question. I'm trying to read an external file I wrote to my desktop with the program. I can correctly search for a match, but when I don't find a match I want it to print "NO MATCH FOUND". However, it prints "NO MATCH FOUND" for each line it didn't find a match in my external file. How would I go about fixing it so It only prints out "NO MATCH FOUND" once?

```
    System.out.println("Enter the email "
        + "address to search for: ");
    String searchterm = reader.next();

    // Open the file as a buffered reader
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
        "/home/damanibrown/Desktop/contactlist.txt"));

    // Start a line count and declare a string to hold our current line.
    int linecount = 0;
    String line;

    // Let the user know what we are searching for
    System.out.println("Searching for " + searchterm
        + " in file...");

    // Loop through each line, put the line into our line variable.
    while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {

        // Increment the count and find the index of the word
        linecount++;
        int indexfound = line.indexOf(searchterm);

        // If greater than -1, means we found a match
        if (indexfound > -1) {
            System.out.println("Contact was FOUND\n"
                + "Contact " + linecount + ": " + line);
        }
    }
    // Close the file after done searching
    bf.close();
} 

catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
}

break;
```

Comment: Is this the right code? I dont see any println for no match foudn

Comment: Exit the loop the first time match is not found. If you need to know how many mismatches are there, count them inside the loop, but print the message outside the loop if such counter is more than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that your loop will print out the "Contact was FOUND" part for EACH line that matches (I assume because there could be more than one)... Since that's the case, you'll need to use another flag to determine if any matches were made, then output if there weren't any.

Try this for your while loop:

```
    // Loop through each line, put the line into our line variable.
    boolean noMatches = true;
    while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {

        // Increment the count and find the index of the word
        linecount++;
        int indexfound = line.indexOf(searchterm);

        // If greater than -1, means we found a match
        if (indexfound > -1) {
            System.out.println("Contact was FOUND\n"
                    + "Contact " + linecount + ": " + line);
            noMatches = false;
        }
    }
    // Close the file after done searching
    bf.close();
    if ( noMatches ) {
        System.out.println( "NO MATCH FOUND.\n" );
    }
```

Comment: Going to give it a try now.